# Thunar custom actions appearance conditions: don't show up when no files selected

Tags: linux, thunar

I have a thunar custom action for archiving selected files in one click. The problem is that the custom action shows up in the menu even if no files/directories are selected. How do I prevent this behavior?

Comment: maybe you should ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/, that's what I do, and keep superuser for Windows stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the custom action shows up in the menu even if no files/directories
>   are selected

That is not really true. **Thunar considers the directory you are in as being selected** and you cannot open the file manager without opening some directory (when you start Thunar from launcher you open the `$HOME` directory), and custom actions that have *Directories* box checked under *Appearance conditions* will show like that.

### Is this a bug?

Not necessarily.

Some custom actions could be imagined that are useful for the folder you are in, like *Search* (`catfish %f`), *Open in terminal* (`exo-open --working-directory %f --launch TerminalEmulator`) or *Open as root* (`gksu Thunar %F`).

One could even imagine custom actions used independently of selected files or folders - and when none is - namely commands that are not affecting a selected file or folder (or the folder we are in), but only the programs and/or files specified in the very command of the custom action: for example an action that will simply [backup all my present Thunar custom actions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395066/is-it-possible-to-backup-and-restore-thunar-custom-actions): `cp -f ~/.config/Thunar/uca.xml /path/to/dropbox/etc`.

### Is there a way around that?

I am not aware of one, excepting the fact that **in Thunar you should already have an archiving option without the need for you to create that as a custom action**. (Or do you need that for a special type of archiving?)

[image]

Be sure you have `thunar-archive-plugin` installed, as well as `file-roller`.

As the above option "Create archive" will appear **only** when files and folders are selected with the cursor, that may offer a clue: **if it were** a custom action, you could just look in its settings and apply those to you action. But it is **not** present in Thunar's GUI options for custom actions (that reflect the settings in `~/.config/Thunar/uca.xml`) and I do **not** think it is a custom action: trying to look deeper for other files I couldn't find something similar to  `~/.config/Thunar/uca.xml` in the system files etc.
In fact the `file-roller` utility seems to add that context menu option through a script (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/thunar-archive-plugin/file-roller.tap`), not as a custom action. Its description is this:

```
Wrapper script to create and extract archive files
#                   in Thunar, via the thunar-archive-plugin, using the
#                   file-roller archive manager
```

But having that plugin and the archiver installed might solve your problem. On a Debian-based system:

```
sudo apt-get install file-roller thunar-archive-plugin
```

Comment: The question is about special type of archiving so `thunar-archive-plugin` is not an option.

Comment: @user619271 - This might interest you: `The Thunar Archive Plugin currently includes support for File Roller and Ark, but support for other archive managers can easily be added by installing a .tap wrapper script in addition to the .desktop file for that application (see the README file in the source tarball). ` - from [here](http://www.home.unix-ag.org/bmeurer/projects/thunar-archive-plugin/index.html). Maybe your special type of archiving command could be added into such a `.tap` wrapper - although it seems too much work for a small problem.